# Update quantity of items in basket page from localStorage in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, local-storage

I am using react and globalContext to add items to a cart page and this adds the product to the array stored in localStorage and looks like this.

```
0: {id: "9", title: "Apple Watch SE 40mm (GPS) - Space Grey Aluminium Case with Midnight Sport Band",…}
id: "9"
price: 249.99
quantity: 1
src: "/static/media/se.0ca02982636517aed223.png"
title: "Apple Watch SE 40mm (GPS) - Space Grey Aluminium Case with Midnight Sport Band"
```

I have a quantity selector on the page for every item added to the basket which displays the quantity how do i make it so when that quantity is changed the price alters too?

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faChevronLeft, faClose, faPlus, faMinus } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import { GlobalContext } from '../context/GlobalState'

export const Basket = () => {

  const {basket, removeFromCart} = useContext(GlobalContext)

  let cartArray = localStorage.getItem("basket");
  cartArray = JSON.parse(cartArray);
  const total = cartArray.reduce((prev, cur) => (cur.price * cur.quantity) + prev, 0);
  console.log(total)

  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0);
  const handleReduceQuantity = () => {
    if (quantity === 0) return;
    setQuantity((prev) => prev - 1);
  };

  const handleIncreaseQuantity = () => {
    setQuantity((prev) => prev + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="h-screen bg-zinc-100 p-4">
      
      <div className="py-5">
        <div className="max-w-md mx-auto bg-white shadow-lg rounded-lg md:max-w-7xl">
          <div className="md:flex">
            <div className="w-full p-4">
              <div className="md:grid md:grid-cols-3 gap-2 ">                          
                <div className="col-span-2 p2 md:p-5">
                  <h1 className="text-xl font-bold ">Shopping Basket</h1>
                  <div className="flex justify-between flex-col items-center mt-6 pt-6 gap-12">
                    {basket.length > 0 ? (
                      <>
                      {basket.map(item => (
                        <>
                          <div className='flex flex-col w-full justify-between md:gap-44 items-start'>
                            <div className="flex items-center">
                              <img src={item.src} className="rounded w-20 " />
                              <div className="flex flex-col ml-3 gap-1 ">
                                <span className="md:text-lg text-sm font-bold w-full md:t-width ">{item.title}</span>
                                <span className="text-xl font-bold">£ {item.price}</span>
                              </div>
                              <div className="flex items-center justify-between py-2 bg-gray-100 rounded-md md:w-36">
                                <FontAwesomeIcon
                                  icon={ faMinus }
                                  className="ml-4 transform scale-110 cursor-pointer text-primary"
                                  onClick={handleReduceQuantity}
                                />
                                <span className="text-lg font-bold text-secondary-dark">
                                  {item.quantity}
                                </span>
                                <FontAwesomeIcon 
                                  icon={ faPlus }
                                  className="mr-4 transform scale-110 cursor-pointer text-black"
                                  onClick={handleIncreaseQuantity}
                                />
                              </div>
                              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={ faClose }  onClick={() => 
                                removeFromCart(item.id)}/>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          
                        </>
                      ))}
                      </>
                    ) : (
                      <div>No Items</div>
                    )}
                    
                  </div>
    
                  <div className="flex justify-between items-center mt-6 pt-6 border-t">
                  <NavLink to="/">
                    <div className="flex items-center"> <i className="fa fa-arrow-left text-sm pr-2"></i> 
                    <span className="text-md font-medium text-amz hover:text-orange-500 cursor-pointer "> 
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={ faChevronLeft }></FontAwesomeIcon> Continue Shopping</span> 
                    </div>
                  </NavLink>
                    <div className="flex justify-center items-end"> 
                      <span className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-400 mr-1">Subtotal:</span> 
                      <span className="text-lg font-bold text-gray-800 ">£ {total}</span> 
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className=" p-5 bg-gray-800 rounded overflow-visible"> 
                  <span className="text-xl font-medium text-gray-100 block pb-3">Total</span> 
                  <div className="flex justify-center flex-col pt-3"> 
                    <label className="text-xs text-gray-400 ">Name on Card</label> 
                    <input type="text" className="focus:outline-none w-full h-6 bg-gray-800 text-white placeholder-gray-300 text-sm border-b border-gray-600 py-4" placeholder="Giga Tamarashvili"/> 
                  </div>
                  <div className="flex justify-center flex-col pt-3"> 
                    <label className="text-xs text-gray-400 ">Card Number</label> 
                    <input type="text" className="focus:outline-none w-full h-6 bg-gray-800 text-white placeholder-gray-300 text-sm border-b border-gray-600 py-4" placeholder="**** **** **** ****"/> 
                  </div>
                  <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-2 pt-2 mb-3">
                    <div className="col-span-2 "> 
                      <label className="text-xs text-gray-400">Expiration Date</label>
                      <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2"> 
                        <input type="text" className="focus:outline-none w-full h-6 bg-gray-800 text-white placeholder-gray-300 text-sm border-b border-gray-600 py-4" placeholder="mm"/> 
                        <input type="text" className="focus:outline-none w-full h-6 bg-gray-800 text-white placeholder-gray-300 text-sm border-b border-gray-600 py-4" placeholder="yyyy"/> 
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className=""> 
                      <label className="text-xs text-gray-400">CVV</label> <input type="text" className="focus:outline-none w-full h-6 bg-gray-800 text-white placeholder-gray-300 text-sm border-b border-gray-600 py-4" placeholder="XXX"/> 
                    </div>
                  </div> 
                  <button className="h-12 w-full bg-blue-500 rounded focus:outline-none text-white hover:bg-blue-600">Check Out</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

At the moment the quantity selector is just a counter and doesn't change the quantity of the item in localStorage and therefore doesn't change the total price.

Comment: First thing first, if you want to update the quantity, change it in the localStorage also. I am assuming that the products in the cart might be different right? Then, on each quantity change, whether add or delete, set the quantity in the localstorage and calculate the total price `const total = cartArray.reduce((prev, cur) => (cur.price * cur.quantity) + prev, 0);` like this as you have already done.

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: I have posted a sample code for your reference. Hope this might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const items = [
    {
    id: "9",
    price: 200,
    quantity: 1,
    src: "/static/media/se.0ca02982636517aed223.png",
    title: "Apple Watch SE 40mm (GPS) - Space Grey Aluminium Case with Midnight Sport Band",
    },
  {
    id: "3",
    price: 300,
    quantity: 1,
    src: "/static/media/se.0ca02982636517aed223.png",
    title: "Apple Watch SE 40mm (GPS) - Space Grey Aluminium Case with Midnight Sport Band",
    }
];

const calculateTotal = (items) => {
        const total = items.reduce((acc, curr) => (curr.price * curr.quantity) + acc, 0);
    console.log(total);
}

const handleQuantityUpdate = (itemId, operation) => {
    const newItems = items.map((i) => {
        if(i.id === itemId){
        return {...i, quantity: operation === 'increase' ? i.quantity + 1 : i.quantity - 1};
      }
      return {...i};
    });
    //need to store into localstorage at this point
    console.log(newItems);
    calculateTotal(newItems);
}

handleQuantityUpdate("9", 'increase'); 
handleQuantityUpdate("3", "decrease");
```